# Powershell take list of servers, and add "server" property

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm looking to combine data from two sources in an existing script.

I have one list of servers which is pulled via a Citrix command called `Get-XAServer`. Using this cmdlet, an array is created, with two properties, `server` and `logonmode`. Running `$1stList` looks like this:

```
SERVER  LOGONMODE
Server1 AllowLogOns
Server2 AllowLogOns
```

Now, I want to update this list of servers that can't be pulled via the `get-XAserver` cmdlet. So, inside the script, I've just got an array variable that's like this, but from a list of servers that's in the following format:

```
$2ndList = "Server3", "Server4", "Server5"
```

Problem is, the `server` property isn't attached to the 2nd list. So, when i try to combine the arrays, they aren't parsed properly.

How do I iterate through the 2nd list so that the `server` and `logonmode` properties are both added to each/every server in the `$2ndList` array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `foreach`:

```
foreach ($server in $2ndlist) {
    $1stList += [pscustomobject]@{ 
        SERVER = $server
        LOGONMODE = ""
    }
}
```

Or a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
$2ndList | % {
    $1stList += [pscustomobject]@{ 
        SERVER = $_
        LOGONMODE = ""
    }
}
```